# 2DS Data Transfer

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I, up until last week, owned a 2DS and had SSB4 as a download. However, the screen is damaged to the point of no functioning image. I initially thought that just popping the SD card into my new unused 2DS would be all I needed to do. That failed. I just read that data transfer is used to get it over, so I ask this- Is there anything that could impede data transfer? I am using the receiving 2DS, and using noise as a guide, to verify the buttons I'm tapping. I have gotten to the "Send" and "Receive" on each, but they're not transferring. I have not gotten a pop-up for number of transfers remaining, so if that's a factor, then this entire problem grows exponentially harder.

I will most likely be unable to monitor this actively, but will check every evening if anyone has thoughts and needs more information. That shouldn't be a problem, as other that SSB4, there's nothing taking up space, and the new 2DS was opened an hour before the writing of this.

Thank you for any input you can provide
P.S. Don't let a perfectly good system get stepped on.

Comment: if you can't see the screen, how do you know for sure that the broken 2DS is actually transferring? All the buttons sound the same to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact the Nintendo customer services and request that your Nintendo network profile be transferred to the new system. They will walk you through the process, and it will work. I did the same thing not to long ago.

Comment: Only if you manage to persuade Nintendo to do this. In my experience, they are not very lenient, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: i was lucky i guess

Comment: Nintendo **can and will do this**.